# Converting count query to a list in contain statement in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a custom finder which gets notifications for current user for an item. Notifications are grouped by their messages like "new_comment". Wth query I have message, message_count in my results

Is there a way to convert this query within the finder in key => value format so I can have it in message => message_format

```
//finder code;
return $query->contain([
        'Notifications' => function ($q)use($userId) {

            $q->select(['item_id','message','message_count'=> 'COUNT(message)']);
            $q->where(['Notifications.user_id' => $userId]);
            $q->group(['Notifications.message']);

            return $q;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Quick update. I realize I can use collection($q)->combine('message', 'message_count'); after $query but this throws an error when I return it from.   Call to undefined method ArrayIterator::aliasFields()

Comment: why not use counterCache  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html to store counts in users table  and use simple find('list') to retrive messages?

Comment: Use the Cake\Collection\Collection's combine method.

Comment: @user3733648 check my first comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Cake\Collection\Collection`'s `combine` method

Comment: I already mentioned about trying this method under original post but it didn't work.